# Add endpoint to Sitefinity site

Tags: c#, sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I have an endpoint I want to add to a Sitefinity installation. Essentially, I'm going to call an API and then return some json to an AJAX call from another page.

I figure I can create a blank template and a custom widget that does just that, since I have experience creating Sitefinity MVC widgets.

There is probably a less wrong way to do this though. Can I somehow (without much more work than creating a blank theme and a custom Widget in the CMS) create a one-off C# page that is publicly accessible?

Comment: What do you mean by `a one-off C# page that is publicly accessible`?

Comment: @VictorLeontyev something in the MVC rather than the CMS side that's publicly accessible, I'm not 100% certain how MVC routing works here with Sitefinity controlling page urls through the CMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about [Classic MVC mode](https://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-classic-mvc-mode)

1) You can define route in your Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bootstrapper.Initialized += Bootstrapper_Initialized;
}

void Bootstrapper_Initialized(object sender, Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ExecutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Bootstrapped")
    {
        System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.MapRoute(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes,
         "Classic",
         "customprefix/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         new { controller = "Feature", action = "Index", id = (string)null }
        );
    }
}
```

2) Create normal MVC controller with Views and Models

3) Access it by this URL `http://localhost/customprefix/{controller}/{action}/{id}`